# Error handling in Excel VBA connecting to remote MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I'm creating a macro to connect an excel sheet to a SQL server.
The excel file will be used both when I'm home and when I'm outside.
Now everything is working adressing to my DNS www.server1.com.

Now, if for some reason the server 1 is not working, I want to adress to the second backup server www.server2.com

The problem is that I cannot handle the error.
after the "Cn.Open ...." if it cannot communicate with the server, the macro is stopped and I receive the excel error:
"Run-rime error: '-2147467259 (80004005)"

I want that instead of return this error, I can manually handle the error with something like that:
If Cn.Error Then
Server_Name = "www.server2.com"
etc ...

How can I do that?

```
Server_Name = "www.server1.com" ' Enter your server name here
Port = "3306"
Database_Name = "mydb" ' Enter your database name here
User_ID = "myuserid" ' enter your user ID here
Password = "mypassword" ' Enter your password here

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

Cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server=" & Server_Name & ";PORT=" & Port & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";Uid=" & User_ID & " ;Pwd=" & Password & ";"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `On Error ...` and test on the next line if you are connected; if you aren't, then connect to your backup server. Finally, deactivate the error handling.

```
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

On Error Resume Next
Cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server=" & Server_Name & ";PORT=" & Port & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";Uid=" & User_ID & " ;Pwd=" & Password & ";"

if Cn.State = 0 Then : _
    Cn.Open ... 'Backup connection

On Error Goto 0
```